# How to add more brokers in Kafka Docker using docker-compose

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm running Confluent Docker. I am trying to add more brokers using docker-compose.

(I tried `docker-compose scale kafka=3` but didn't work for me.)

This is my `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: '2'
services:

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

#To add more broker, do I do the following? 

KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2        // just add this? 
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
```

1) To add more brokers, what do I need to add or change in `docker-compose.yml`?

2) Why does Docker use another port 29092? When I run Kafka in non-docker mode, I just needed one port (9092).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use scale because the broker ids need to be different.

And you're missing this top section from the new service

You need two ports because one allows kafka clients on the host to access Kafka (9092), and the other allows Docker services to reach Kafka (29092).

```
broker2:
   image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.3.1
   hostname: broker2
   container_name: broker2
   depends_on:
      - zookeeper
   ports:
       - "29192:29092" # technically, this one isn't needed to be mapped from the host 
       - "9192:9092"
   environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
        KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
        CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
        CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
```

If you really want to run a cluster of brokers, though, the Confluent Helm Charts or Strimzi project would be useful, however running multiple Kafka's on one machine isn't improving any performance (they're sharing the same disk, and taking up *more space* via replication) or resiliency (it's all on one machine)